# How to pass params to get required value from array of object by filtering

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build a function, which should accept the parameter and return the value by filtering an array by iterating it's value. I start to get some what looping the values.

But do not know how to declare the function and get return value from the array.  not  able to get some suitable online reference.

code:

```py
lst = [["a", 45], ["b", 40], ["c", 18], ["d", 17]]

for x in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[x][0] == input("Enter your name:"):

        print("Searching in list")
        print("name:", lst[x][0], "age:", lst[x][1])
```

expecting:

```py
getValue(){
findvalue = ("name:", lst[x][0], "age:", lst[x][1])
    return findvalue
}
    
value = getValue(value)
```

Comment: I have difficulty understanding what you want. It sounds like you want something like [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which takes an iterable (for example a list like yours), a predicate (a function to know which items to keep), and will return the items that match the predicate. Please provide an example of inputs and corresponding outputs for the function you want.

Comment: lst = [['a', 45],
       ['b', 40],
       ['c', 18],
       ['d', 17]]

  
for x in range(len(lst)):
   if lst[x][0] == input("Enter your name:"):
     
     print("Searching in list")
     print("name:", lst[x][0], "age:", lst[x][1]);

output:
Enter your name:a
Searching in list
name: a age: 45
Enter your name:b
Searching in list
name: b age: 40
Enter your name:c
Searching in list
name: c age: 18
Enter your name:d
Searching in list
name: d age: 17
The output is not working if i change the order of alphabetes

Answer (score 1):

What I have done :

- store the user input in a variable (`name`) before the loop, so it does not ask at each iteration
- print that we are searching in the list before the loop
- iterate over the list items (variable `item`) instead of its indices

```py
lst = [["a", 45], ["b", 40], ["c", 18], ["d", 17]]

name = input("Enter your name:")

print("Searching in list")
for item in lst:
    if item[0] == name:
        print("name:", item[0], "age:", item[1])
```